# Domain redirecting to localhost/ with index.php, everything else not found?

Tags: redirect, web, localhost

This is so weird. The website manhassetbuzz.tv redirects to $1 even though I removed that redirection in the addon domains. Furthermore the folder is completely empty and the .htaccess is standard.

manhassetbuzz.tv/index.php redirects to Localhost!!

I've got two other domains on this server that work fine.

Comment: What exactly is your question??

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned above is as below.. 
I found that its working..

http://www.manhassetbuzz.tv/index.php